# What's the recommended way to customize toString? Using Symbol.toStringTag or overriding toString?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm confused on what to implement, first, my module will use Babel so there are no problems implementing ES6 features, second, I will use the `class` construct to create class and not the old prototypal method. So now, I'm confused if I'm going to override toString (which is the old way) or just implement Symbol.toStringTag like what this MDN documentation said, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag 
So what is the recommended way?

Comment: *"I will use the class construct to create class and not the old prototypal method."* It's still the "old" prototypical method, it's just simpler syntax if you want to use constructor functions.

Comment: There's hardly ever a reason to use `Symbol.toStringTag`

Comment: yes but for my case I'm doing something that needs the features of Symbol.toStringTag :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

They're for different things entirely.

If you're trying to define the string version of your object, provide a `toString` method.

If you're trying to add information to your class that `Object.prototype.toString` will use to build its `"[object XYZ]"` string, provide a method whose name is the value of `Symbol.toStringTag`.

Here's an illustration of the difference:

```js
class Example {
    constructor(x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    toString() {
        return `Example[x=${this.x}]`;
    }
    get [Symbol.toStringTag]() {
        return "Example";
    }
}
const e =  new Example(42);
console.log(e.toString());                      // Example[x=42]
console.log(String(e));                         // Example[x=42]
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(e)); // [object Example]
```

If we hadn't provided that `get [Symbol.toStringTag]`, that last line would output `"[object Object]"` rather than `"[object Example]"`.

Note that it doesn't *have* to be a getter, it can be a data property instead. Since you're using Babel, you could define it like this if you include [Public Class Fields](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-public-fields/) support (currently Stage 2):

```
class Example {
    constructor(x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    toString() {
        return `Example[x=${this.x}]`;
    }
    [Symbol.toStringTag] = "Example";
}
```

...although of course it would be writable. Alternately:

```
class Example {
    constructor(x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    toString() {
        return `Example[x=${this.x}]`;
    }
}
Object.defineProperty(Example.prototype, Symbol.toStringTag, {
    value: "Example"
});
```

Comment: So that's what toStringTag is used for! :D I just decided to use both, because I'm experimenting something.

Comment: Also note that toStringTag is displayed in the developer console when you log an object, unlike toString(). You get something like "Foo{...}" where Foo is the tag.