# ES6 how to override toString() method?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

In ES5 style javascript, to override the `toString` method I would simply do the following:

```
function myFunction() {
}

myFunction.prototype.toString = function() {
    return "My amazing function";
};

var myAmazingFunc = new myFunction();
console.log(myAmazingFunc);
```

In my current code I use ES6 and my object is now a class (which essentially is a function).

```
class MyAwesomeClass {
    // awesome code goes here
}
```

What I have tried to do to override the `toString` method are the following:

```
class MyAwesomeClass {
    toString() {
        return "Awesome";
    }
}
```

And also

```
class MyAwesomeClass {
    // awesome code goes here
}
MyAwesomeClass.prototype.toString = function() {
    return "Awesome";
};
```

Also without the `prototype` - but still it does not seem it's being called.
How is this possible in ES6 class?

Comment: I've checked in Chrome console and both your solutions work. What's the problem exactly? Is your source code transpiled by Babel, which could cause some side effect?

Comment: No transpilation. In my actual code I have also place `console.log` inside the `toString` method and it's not printed out.

Comment: What are you trying to call `toString` for? The class or the object? Note that `console.log(myAmazingFunc);` does *not* execute `toString`.

Comment: Are you just doing `console.log(new MyAwesomeClass())` in a browser? Because browser's `console.log` won't invoke `toString` - it displays objects in-depth and stringifying everything would destroy the debugging capabilities. How about `console.log("" + new MyAwesomeClass())? This will force stringification as part of the coercing process required for concatenation. Also, note that whatever ES6 class is doing or not doing, your first, ES5 code snippet does the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the recommended way to customize toString? Using Symbol.toStringTag or overriding toString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42886953/whats-the-recommended-way-to-customize-tostring-using-symbol-tostringtag-or-ov)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This actually does work:

```js
class MyAwesomeClass {
  toString() {
    console.log("toString called");
    return "Awesome";
  }
}

console.log(new MyAwesomeClass() + "!!!");
```

There must be something wrong with how you're testing (hint: `console.log` doesn't trigger `toString`).

If you're looking for a way to customize the `console.log` output, this is only possible in node.js (https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_custom_inspection_functions_on_objects), by adding a custom `inspect` method. This feature is deprecated though as of node 10.

Comment: Thanks. The `console.log` prints out the `json` representation of the class. Is it not something overridable by the `toString` method?

Comment: @developer82 There is no JSON involved here. JSON is a textual serialization format, the class structure does not have anything to do with JSON.

Comment: Thanks. My problem was that I thought the `toString` is also triggered when on the `console.log`. If I actually do a `toString` than it works. No way to control the erlier?

Comment: @developer82 - If you really want to change the behavior of `console.log` you can overwrite the definition of `console.log` itself, but make sure you know exactly what you're doing and why you want to do that in the first place.

Comment: Sure you can. `let oldlog = console.log.bind(console); console.log = (...args) => oldlog(...args.map(x => x.toString()))` - but you'll hate it as soon as you need to debug anything, (hint: `[object Object]`)

Answer (score 12):

The `console.log()` will not call the `toString()` method for you... you also need to use the `${}`

```js
class MyAwesomeClass {
  toString() {
    console.log("toString called");
    return "Awesome";
  }
}

let e = new MyAwesomeClass();
console.log(`${e}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you instantiating the class first? If I create a class:

`class myclass {}`

and add a prototype, or even just the standard way:

```
myclass.prototype.toString = () => "hi"
// or, using the class syntax
class myclass {
    toString() {
       return "hi"
    }
}
```

then I can instantiate the class and it works:

```
new myclass().toString()
> "hi"
```

Perhaps you are trying to call it on the static, uninstantiated class itself. In order to do that, you need to add a static method to the class.

```
class myclass {
    static toString() {
        return "myclass toString"
    }
}
```

So when you call this on a non-instantiated version of the class, you get the overridden method:

```
myclass.toString()
> "myclass toString"
```

Comment: That's not it. OP's `toString` works. The problem is he expects `console.log` to call it for him, but `console.log` is all like ["I don't work here, lady."](https://www.reddit.com/r/IDontWorkHereLady/).